# Is there anything like a delimited key-value pair in .NET?

Tags: .net, dictionary, key-value, c#-6.0, key-value-coding

An easy example of a delimited key-value pair is `name=brady`? Concatenation is far simply in this case of one pair, but I'm thinking of a dictionary consisting of such pairs. I'm dealing a lot with sets of these values as form data and in other contexts, and quickly made a rough dictionary, but would like to refine it for future use if it's not re-inventing the wheel.

**The point of this question is**, does the special key-value pair I want exist[1], and if it doesn't, I will extend `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, as was always my attention.

Sometimes people ask very stupid questions here, so I forgive those who answered this one as if I were as skilled a coder as a lump of rock.

[1] It does, but is MS code and only has internal accessibility, as Paulo Morgado pointed out. Now if MS has such a class, why did they not just stick a plain dictionary, like some people are telling me to do.

Comment: Could you provide more details? How is this different to `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`?

Comment: There is an also an existing `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` generic struct (which is used by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`). Sounds like you just need a `Parse()` function for your data.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore The extended dictionary has pair delimiters, pair separators, character escaping functions, and a `ToString()` that concatenates them all like form data normally is, and a `Parse()` function, maybe a `Sort()` by key or by value, to start with. It's just more convenient than always using `Dictionary<string,string>` and manually doing the rest.

Comment: how about extending `Dictionary<string,string>` yourself with the methods you mentioned ?

Comment: So the important part here is *not* that you can keep the data in memory in a key/value pair data structure (like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`), but that you can convert to and from strings?. The question mentions no such thing.

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a serializer for a `Dictionary<K,V>`, not a separate collection type.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore It has a serialiser that outputs the name-value pairs as a character delimited string, with that character defaulting to `=`, and a parser than splits the pairs when added to the dictionary. I have way too many `string.Join()` and `string.Split()` occurrences everywhere.

Comment: @Motivated That is exactly what I want and am asking about. I just don't want to build it if it exists. DRY.

Comment: @svick I'm looking for a dictionary with such a serializer, which would be a derived class of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which seems pretty much to me like a separate collection type.

Comment: @ProfK Well, you probably should not. I think serialization is a separate concern, so it should be a separate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not public and I recall it having roundtrip issues, but you can take a look at the [HttpValueCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/UrlUtility.cs,42d7707c9315ba63)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You need to flesh this out so that it contains enough content that it answers the question even _without_ the link.

Comment: Thank you for being the only reader here to understand what I meant.

Comment: I think a small copy and paste, with a few tweaks, and the `HttpValueCollection` source will do nicelt, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx

HttpUtility provides means to manage this type of collection from string.

```
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
parameters["foo"] = "text";
parameters["baz"] = "asdff=32322";
Console.WriteLine(parameters.ToString());

parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parameters.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(parameters["foo"]);
Console.WriteLine(parameters["baz"]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Seeing that other commentators have all told me to use a normal dictinary, or a special serializer for one, which I intended to do anyway if there wasn't already such a dictionary.